# Resources.Load doesn't grab values of my child class

Tags: c#, unity

I have a parent class `Unit`, and child classes `melee unit`/`ranged unit`. The parent class  holds uninitialized fields such as `health`, `damage`, etc. the child class sets the values of these fields in an Awake function.

In another script, I have a Start method:

```
void Start(){
    gridX=5;
    gridY=5;
    for (int i = 0; i<(gridY*gridX);i++){
        allies.Add(new GameObject());
    }
    AddUnits();
    SetupGrid();


}
```

AddUnits looks like this:

```
void AddUnits(){
        allies[0] = (GameObject) Resources.Load ("Units/melee unit");
        allies[1] = (GameObject) Resources.Load ("Units/ranged unit);
        number = 2;
    }
```

The resources loaded are prefab gameobjects containing their respective melee unit or ranged unit script (both which derives from base class `Unit`)However, when I check the health value of the gameobjects `allies`, they're always 0. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 4):

When a Resource is Loaded its not actually Instantiated and added to the Scene so Awake() is never called. Change your code to something like the following:

```
allies[0] = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Units/melee unit", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
```

[Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)